# Как прочитать данные с файла fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

есть файл input.txt, в нем три строки, данные из первой строки этого файла нужно передать переменной `int n`, на первой строке только одна цифра. на двух остальных цифры, разделенные пробелом, их нужно передать двум массивам: `int1[n]`, `int2[n]`. Я вроде помню, что это можно сделать с помощью оператора >>. пока только загрузил файл:
`ofstream input("input.txt", ios_base::in);`

спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
input >> n;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) input >> int1[i];
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) input >> int2[i];
```

Comment: ошибку выдает:

main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: 

main.cpp:62:8: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::ofstream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ofstream<char>’} and ‘int’)

 input >> n;

Comment: @foreignperson разумеется выдаёт, у вас же `ofstream` (то есть output file stream, для записи). Для чтения нужен `ifstream` (то есть input file stream)

Comment: спасибо, все сработало.